# how to handle if ip or domain are wrong in fetch in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

when ip or domain is wrong in request using fetch in javascript is there any solution ? to handle stop request if ip or domain is provided wrong.

var ip_or_domain=192.168.1.1

```
fetch(ip_or_domain+'/something-get-api')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

Comment: based on which criteria you will decide is wrong? I mean. if you want ip_or_domain=192.168.1.1 then you can simply wrap the entire fetch inside an if statement.

Comment: @Prabusamvel i can't hard code that if IP is right or wrong becuase in future IP may change so i can't put in one constant file and check from there in my case that is not possible solution. thanks for reply.

Comment: What about a global array where you can store all of the possible correct IP's. then you can simply use array.indexOf in an if before fetch.?

Comment: @Prabusamvel no because user had to enter IP address itself from input before sync process i need to think for backend side solution thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an error, you can `catch` it:

```
fetch(ip_or_domain+'/something-get-api')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: no for error i now but how to handle if IP is wrong in request

Comment: @jaythanki without knowing the correct domain/ip you can't achieve what you want.

Comment: @VikashSingh yes you are right but in my case employee had to enter SERVER_IP from the input itself for sync process than i need to go with other solutions.  thanks for reply

Comment: @jaythanki since the control has been given to user to enter ip as input then its the user responsibility to provide correct ip. In my opinion this design flaw, My suggestion is to allow user to edit the ip later if user has entered the wrong ip. Also you should throw error and inform user that ip entered is wrong. My another suggestion would be to check ip correctness before saving.

Comment: @VikashSingh yes employee can edit ip address but can't check IP at run time because i had no IP address in Frontend system before sync process I need to think that from backend to compare IP address to compare before sync process.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some way to validate the values the only other way to know if it is valid or not is to actually make the request

You need to implement error handling yourself. Start by checking `response.ok` and throw an error if it is false then use `catch()` for errors.

You can also check `response.status` for more granular errors

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
   return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(myBlob) { 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ip_wishlist = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']; 
// where you can keep the ip_wishlist dynamically in a global array.

if(ip_wishlist.indexOf(ip_or_domain) !== -1){

 fetch(ip_or_domain+'/something-get-api')
 .then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
 })
.then(function(myJson) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
 })
.catch(function(error) {
 console.log(error);
 });

}
```